# 8-Bit quantized model showing better train accuracy than Full precision model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, quantization

I am trying to compare accuracy between Full precision model and 8 Bit quantized model and I found that the Quantized model has greater training accuracy than Full precision. Is this possible? My dataset consists of 8000 train and 2000 test image. However, the validation accuracy of Full precision is greater than an 8-Bit model is as expected.
For 8-Bit quantization, I am using work done by Bert-moons (https://github.com/BertMoons/)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That's why validation and test accuracies matter. Even with those, your results are as good as your data. You should also look into k-fold cross-validation for such cases.

Comment: thanks for note but isn't this strange that reduced precision which in usual terms thought to be more accurate compared to reduced precision. Is there any explanation for this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Somewhat unimagined, but not completely unpredictable, we never search the complete search space so it's possible that an even better model exists. Also, it performs better for the data that you currently have, it may not for any other data, it may even be less generalized than high precision model.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. So once we do some run on bigger datasets then it will be more conclusive to draw the conclusion.